# IE7/IE8 z-index not cooperating. Suggestions?

Tags: css, xhtml, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

**EDIT: Solution found.** The pink block had `overflow:visible !important`, which in Internet Explorer invalidated z-index. After removing it, the logo came to the top.

See: http://bit.ly/i7ER3e

See logo "********" (beside top menu) with Firefox/Chrome, it correctly appears above left-content block (the block with pink background).

In IE7/IE8 the logo, it becomes hidden behind the pink block.

I've been messing with this for 2 hours now. Tried a lot of stuff. Can't get it to appear right in IE7/IE8.

Any suggestions?

(**Note**: I'm working in a really restrictive framework where I cannot simply float the logo before the menu. I have to use position:absolute to place it.)

Comment: somehow this cell is ineriting..line-height of body..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not z-index in your case

your body has some line height which is not sufficent...

```
line-height:180%
```

change this to 200 or so it works, but still that is not good approach

but just found the issue....

Comment: Thanks for replying. But this didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
z-index: -1;
```

for the elements that should be below the logo.

Answer (score 0):

try setting `position:relative;` as well as the z-index.

The default position style is `position:static;`, and IE has bugs around the z-index handling when combined with static positioning; setting position:relative can solve some of them, without affecting too much else.

See [this page for more info](http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/). (the link is for CSS3Pie, which is an IE hack to help it support some CSS3 features like border-radius, but the info on the z-index bug is general and likely covers your issue as well)